# How to override array and save it to a file?

Tags: java

In class, we are creating a program which is an inventory for car parts. We open a text file that contains car parts, and we could search for a specific part using the name, part name, stock amount, serial number, and price. Once we find the name, part name, stock amount, serial number, or price, we could change it using these text fields. Whatever is entered in the text field is then saved into an array, however, I need to override the array with new information and save it to the text file. How would I be able to do that?

```
public class CarPartsGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public CarPartsGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

//OBJECT ARRAY
CarPart[] partsArray;

int location;
int arraySize;
//variables for array

String make;
String name;
String serialNumber;
double price;
int onHand;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    inputTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    openButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    findButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    updateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    partNamTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    onHandTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    serialNumTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    priceTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    display = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    makeTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    clearButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Enter File Name:");

    openButton.setText("OPEN");
    openButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    saveButton.setText("SAVE");
    saveButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            saveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    findButton.setText("FIND");
    findButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            findButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    updateButton.setText("UPDATE");
    updateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            updateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    partNamTxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            partNamTxtActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Part Name");

    jLabel3.setText("On Hand");

    jLabel4.setText("Serial #");

    jLabel5.setText("Price");

    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setColumns(20);
    display.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(display);

    jLabel6.setText("Make");

    clearButton.setText("CLEAR");
    clearButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            clearButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(inputTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 312, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(findButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(openButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(saveButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(updateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(clearButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(onHandTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(partNamTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(serialNumTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(priceTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(makeTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(inputTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(openButton)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                    .addComponent(saveButton)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(findButton)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(updateButton)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(clearButton)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(makeTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(partNamTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(onHandTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(serialNumTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(priceTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19))))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
 //C:/Users/287648/Desktop/ExhaustParts.txt
private void openButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
  try{
      File file = new File(inputTxt.getText());
      FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader bRGetNumLines = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);
      int lines = 0;
      while(bRGetNumLines.readLine()!= null){
          lines++;
      }
      fileReader1.close();
      arraySize = lines/5;
      partsArray = new CarPart[arraySize];


      FileReader fileReader2 = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader2);
      String line;
      for(int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++){
          make = bufferedReader.readLine();
          name = bufferedReader.readLine();
          serialNumber = bufferedReader.readLine();
          price = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());
          onHand = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
          partsArray[counter] = new CarPart(name, serialNumber, price, onHand, make);
          display.append(partsArray[counter].getMake()+"  ");
          display.append(partsArray[counter].getName()+"  ");
          display.append(partsArray[counter].getSerialNum()+"  ");
          display.append(Double.toString(partsArray[counter].getPrice())+"  ");
          display.append(Integer.toString(partsArray[counter].getOnHand())+"  ");
          display.append("\n");
      }
      fileReader2.close();
  }
  catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(inputTxt, "File not found");
    }
  catch (IOException e){
  }
}                                          

private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    //saves every update, and overrides new information
    // overrides array
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(inputTxt.getText(), false));
        for (int i = 0; partsArray.length; i++) {
            CarPart x = partsArray[i];
            writer.write(x);

        }
    }
}                                          

private void findButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String sNum;
    sNum = serialNumTxt.getText();
    location = 0;
    boolean cont = true;
    while(location < arraySize && cont){
        if(partsArray[location].getSerialNum().equals(sNum))
            cont = false;
        else location++;
    }
    if(location == arraySize)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Serial Number Not Found");
    else{
        display.setText(null);
        display.append(partsArray[location].getMake());
        display.append(partsArray[location].getName());
        display.append(partsArray[location].getSerialNum());
        display.append(Double.toString(partsArray[location].getPrice()));
        display.append(Integer.toString(partsArray[location].getOnHand()));
    }

}                                          

private void updateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String sNum, stock, p;
    sNum = serialNumTxt.getText();
    stock = onHandTxt.getText();
    p = priceTxt.getText();
   if(sNum.equals("")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(serialNumTxt, "Serial Number not entered");
   }
   if(!(p.equals(""))){
      partsArray[location].setPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceTxt.getText()));
   }
   if(!(stock.equals(""))){
       partsArray[location].setOnHand(Integer.parseInt(onHandTxt.getText()));
   }
   if(stock.equals("") && p.equals("")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't enter an update value!");
   }
   display.setText(null);
   display.append(partsArray[location].getMake()+"\n");
   display.append(partsArray[location].getName()+"\n");
   display.append(partsArray[location].getSerialNum()+"\n");
   display.append(Double.toString(partsArray[location].getPrice())+"\n");
   display.append(Integer.toString(partsArray[location].getOnHand())+"\n");
}                                            

private void clearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    inputTxt.setText("");
    display.setText("");
    partNamTxt.setText("");
    onHandTxt.setText("");
    serialNumTxt.setText("");
    priceTxt.setText("");
    makeTxt.setText("");
}
```

Comment: For this, you shouldn't use Streams, you can use `RandomAccessFile` to acheive this, but using is painfull, because you will see the whole file as an array, and you have to skip bytes to do what you want, skiping bytes is painful, cuz you have to know skiped bytes, simply why don't you store the content in XML/JSON format and use some libraries to write your JSON/XML to disk? :)

Comment: Anyway, if you want do it like that (by skipping bytes), consider reading the Javadoc of `RandomAccessFile` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html